# Slow performance running ordered query on SQL Server table with hierarchyid field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

I have a tree of categories stored in a table which at present has both a traditional `ParentCategoryId` field and a hierarchyid field called `Echelon`.

The following query successfully pulls out the data in the format I require, with a depth level and the categories ordered by their depth and by the category name:

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT
        c.Id,
        c.Name,
        c.Echelon,
        c.Echelon AS NewEchelon
    FROM
        Category c
    WHERE
        Deleted IS NULL AND ParentCategoryId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        c2.Id,
        c2.Name,
        c2.Echelon,
        hierarchyid::Parse(q.NewEchelon.ToString() + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.Name) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '/')
    FROM
        q
    JOIN
        Category c2 ON c2.Deleted IS NULL AND c2.Echelon.IsDescendantOf(q.Echelon) = 1 AND c2.Echelon.GetLevel() = q.Echelon.GetLevel() + 1
)
SELECT * FROM q ORDER BY NewEchelon
```

The performance of this query is unfortunately, not great. The real table only has 319 categories, and 89 of them are soft deleted with a non-null value in the `Deleted` column.

The timings for that query are as follows:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(230 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 218 ms,  elapsed time = 321 ms.
```

Now a third of a second seems pretty crazy for such a small amount of data to me. The table has no indexes on it aside from the clustered PK one. Is there a way to rewrite it so that it's faster? Do I just need to add appropriate indexes? Should I look at storing a HierarchySortOrder that I generate with the above query whenever the categories or their structure change? Should I look into caching the category tree at an application level?

My gut tells me that this query shouldn't be taking as long as it is, and that I'm likely missing a trick, but I'd appreciate any advice on the matter!

---

Here is the execution plan:

[Execution Plan http://s27.postimg.org/mo30oy2yp/executionplam.png](http://s27.postimg.org/mo30oy2yp/executionplam.png)
[Link to full sized image](http://s27.postimg.org/mo30oy2yp/executionplam.png)

Comment: Share the sample data and result. if you feel the query can be redesigned.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the data - I've added the execution plan.

Answer (score -1):

The processing time seems fair to me given that its a union query, a few functions and a joins
Also using ***With*** bring a sub-query processing time to take into account

Comment: To accept an answer it really needs to address how to make what I'm doing faster. >300ms may be 'fair', but it's not acceptable for such a simple output of an application.